what is the difference from? npm i react react-dom e npx create-react-app project-name
what is the difference and the best way to install react js? npm install -g create-react-app or npx create-react-app name-project ?
I searched in blos and react documentation but didn't get any answers, I would like a more specific answer

Neither of those. The create-react-app project is dead ~ https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13393. See here for the official  recommendations ~ https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Vite is another popular option similar to create-react-app

First of all, create-react-app is deprecated, so you should probably be using something like Vite instead.
Second, neither of those commands strictly install react. If you just want to install it, run npm i react react-dom in your directory. If you're determined to use create-react-app, the correct way to run it is to use npx create-react-app project-name, because your other command (npm install -g create-react-app) just installs create-react-app globally without running anything.
